# Android - Time wrong milliseconds conversion

Tags: android

I'm having a problem with the conversion of milliseconds time. I'm using the Calendar class to retrieve the current date, in this way:

```
long now = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault()).getTimeInMillis();
```

I store this date in a DB. When I retrieve the date I do the following:

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(unixDate);
    String day = calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault());
    int number = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Unfortunately, I noticed that for some reason, with date near the midnight my code produce a wrong convertion.

For example `1453849440000` which should be `26-01-2016 23.04UTC` is converted to `27-01-2016 00.04`...
I can't figure out what's the problem, any idea?

Comment: So is that the only time it converted wrong? Or is this the problem it is causing everytime?

Comment: Are all your results an hour ahead of UTC? How are you displaying your final result? What time zone is your device set to? (Note that `getTimeInMillis` will bring back UTC no matter what your time zone is set to, but that displaying a time from a Calendar in the default locale will adjust it to display in that time zone.)